# Templated class declaration c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, declaration

I think this is simply an issue of syntax. But no matter how I do this I keep getting compiler errors. I'm using a Node-based list class and can't figure out how to write the declaration header. Where do I place the forward List class declaration, etc? I just don't know how to set this up. Below is the entire declaration header:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class List;

template <typename T>
class Node{
   private:
      Node(T, Node*);
      T data;
      Node* next;
      friend class List<T>;
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const List<T>&);
};

class List{
   public:
      List(int = 0);
      List(const List&);
      ~List();
      bool gotoBeginning();
      bool gotoEnd();
      bool gotoNext();
      bool gotoPrior();
      bool insertAfter(T);
      bool insertBefore(T);
      bool remove(T&);
      bool replace(T);
      bool getCursor(T&) const;
      bool empty() const;
      bool full() const;
      bool clear();
      List<T>& operator=(const List&);
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const List<T>&);
      bool operator==(const List&) const;
  private:
      Node* head;
      Node* cursor;
};
```

Comment: List is not a template, that's it

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: @user1362548: There is no `template <typenane T>` preceding the `class List`. Hence, it is not a template.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
template <class T>
class List
```

and add the T type to the nodes declarations

```
Node<T>* head;
Node<T>* cursor;
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the error `'ostream' does not name a type.` How do I resolve this?

Comment: either change it to `std::ostream` or add `using std::ostream;` after you `#include <ostream>`